# Where does Eclipse store make targets?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Does anyone know where Eclipse store the make targets for C makefile projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make targets configurations are stored in CDT's `.cproject` file located in your project root directory.

Comment: Indeed they are. Thank you