# Eclipse CDT platform independent project

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, multiplatform

I've created a c-project on my linux laptop with Eclipse CDT and everything works fine there.

I now tried to simply open that workspace with its projects but the paths to the includes and compiler aren't right now.

The projects are synced via dropbox and I'd like to stick to that, if it's possible, because I'm switching workplaces quiet often.

How do I setup my Eclipse c project to be openable on both, windows and linux? Can I somehow set platform dependant paths to includes and compiler?

Comment: Consider using CMake project generator

Answer (score 0):

how are you transferring the files from Linux to windows? I suggest using eclipse's "export project" when transferring and be sure to include the makefile which specifies the compilers to be used.

Comment: I'm using dropbox to sync the project and I'd like to stick to that if it's possible because I'm switching my workplaces quiet often :/

Comment: In that case, the makefile should be in the project files.

Comment: Take a look at this post to find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220763/where-does-eclipse-store-make-targets